# How to find drop target item with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find out `id` of the element on which user dropped draggable item. I have tried using `var tar = event.target;` function, but it always returns `id` of main container, not the element I want. How can I fix this? Here is my code:

```
$('.screenContainer').droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var tar = event.target.attributes[1].nodeValue;
    $('#settingsDiv').html('Item id: ' + tar);
    if (!ui.draggable.hasClass('channel')) {
      var Class = ui.draggable.attr("class");
      var title = ui.draggable.text().trim();
      var droppedItemClasses = Class.split(" ");
      var droppedClass = droppedItemClasses[0];
      var item = $('<div class="channel elementTable ' + Class + ' ' + droppedClass + 'Dropped" name="' + title + '" id="' + (fooCount + 1) + '" style="left: ' + droppedLeft + 'px; top: ' + droppedTop + 'px;"></div>');
      $(this).append(item);
      fooCount += 1;
      foo();
    }
  }
});
```

**EDIT:** Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/zbpgf9g6/1/

Comment: What is `event.target.attributes[1].nodeValue;`

Comment: try `event.target.id`  ?

Comment: @Subash I have added the fiddle. Check it out. Drag items to the right container, I need "Target id:" field to show the id.

Comment: `.screenContainer` herewhere you have droppable option. And what `id` you're expecting whether `.mainContainer` `id` or the drapped element `id` I mean `.elementTable` `id` ?

Comment: Use tar = event.originalEvent.target.id in your fiddle. I edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have working snippet. `$(event.target).attr('id')` - It's enough

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( ".screenContainer" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        // Get target id
        var id = $(event.target).attr('id');
        
        // Show id in console
        console.log('id:', id);
        
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  });          
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
  .screenContainer { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; border: 1px solid red; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>
 
<div id="droppable1" class="screenContainer">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable2" class="screenContainer">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable3" class="screenContainer">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable4" class="screenContainer">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

In your example use

```
tar = event.originalEvent.target.id;
```

You can find `id` always in `event.target` or `event.originalEvent.target`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try...

```
$( ".droppable" ).droppable({
        accept: ".draggable",
        helper: "clone",
        hoverClass: "droppable-active",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var $orig = $(ui.draggable);
            if(!$(ui.draggable).hasClass("dropped")) {

                var $el = $orig
                    .clone()
                    .addClass("dropped")
                    .css({"position": "static", "left": null, "right": null})
                    .appendTo(this);

                var id = $el.attr("id");
                alert(id);
               }
         }
 });
```

Comment: I have added the fiddle. Check it out. Drag items to the right container, I need "Target id:" field to show the id, when items are dropped on another item.